# Arctan > 1 newbie question

Tags: trigonometry

It has been quite some time since I've had to compute the theta of an angle.  But given a right angle:

```
  |
  |
b |
  -----------------
        a
```

I'm trying to compute theta (the slope of the angle).  My understanding of trigonometry (as rusty as it is) is that theta = arctan(b/a).  So if b = 50 and a = 1811.  Then using the windows calculator, 50 / 1811 = 0.027609055770292655991165102153506.  Therefore the arctan(b/a) = 1.5814806205083755492980816356377.  If my math is correct, how do I translate this value into the slope of the angle?  It should be around 30-40 degrees, right?

Comment: If a is 50 and b is 1811, a result of 1.6 degrees seems reasonable. 
You can convert between radians and degrees via :
degrees = (180/pi) * radians

Comment: Yep...not sure exactly where you're guessing 30-40 degrees...but no...50/1811 won't give you something like 30-40 degrees.  Think of it this way...50/50 would give you 45 degrees.

Comment: There seems to be some confusing terminology here ... usually theta is used to represent an angle (not the 'slope' of the angle). Slope describes a LINE, it the angle between the line and the x-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
atan2(y, x)
```

will return you the angle in radians (and successfully cope with the cases where x and/or y are 0).

To convert to degrees apply the following formula:

```
double degrees = radians * (180 / PI)
```

Where `PI` is 3.141592... or `math.pi` in c#

Answer (score 0):

If you use a C dialect then there a useful function for just this purpose

```
atan2(y, x);
```

Comment: It seems worth pointing out that the reason this 2-argument function is nice is because a single argument (atan(r)) cannot distinguish between all possible angles, so you will see only 2 quadrants of 4 in the outputs of this function. The 2-arg version notes what quadrant the x-y coords are in and adjusts the result appropriately.